# hg: default server name several local reposotories

Tags: mercurial

I have a plenty of small projects served by hgwebdir and I want to configure local repos such a way I don't need to create almost similar hgrc files for every project:

```
[paths]
default = http:/ /myserver.com/projectN
default-push = http:/ /myserver.com/projectN
```

Can I use some default value like this?

```
[paths]
default = projectN
```

Environment variables won't work (win7).

Comment: Do you want to pre-pend the http://myserver.com to each project's default server path?

Comment: @Mark Yes, if it's possible.

Comment: Doesn't cloning automatically create a good default hgrc?

Comment: @Steve Kaye It does, but it's not the case for my tasks. Not everyone has rigths to create remote repository and clone it when starting new job. Repos are often created locally for new jobs. And unfortunately we never know for future wether this very new job worths creating separate repo for it or it could be just added to some common repo for several small jobs - it is our work spesific. Besides, server with "central" repo can be moved or renamed (that happened 2 or 3 times for the last year) and one would be to manually change paths in all repos or re-pull all of them, that's not convenient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [schemes extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/SchemesExtension). Put something like this in your ~/.hgrc:

```
[extensions]
schemes =

[schemes]
my = http://myserver.com
```

And then your repository hgrc's can contain:

```
[paths]
default = my://projectN
```

Comment: I'm using TortoiseHg, this extension is not distributed along with it. I've downloaded schemes.py and put `schemes=path/to/schemes.py` to hgrc. This doesn't work. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The schemes extension has been part of mercurial for a long time (http://selenic.com/hg/log/7d31f2e42a8a/hgext/schemes.py), and my copy of TortoiseHg certainly includes it. You should just be able to check the "schemes" box in the Extensions section of the TortoiseHg settings - no need to download anything.

Comment: It's not listed in `path/to/TortoiseHg/extension-versions.txt`, so i was sure it's not installed. Shame on me) But anyway i get 404 http error, while server is really accessible by its full name.

Comment: I think the extension-versions.txt file lists *extra* extensions that thg bundles. Extensions that are included by default with mercurial aren't listed.

What do you get if you type "hg id --debug my://projectN" (or whatever your scheme is)? You should see the expanded URL that it is using.

Comment: Space in repository name - that's what caused the error.  Though usual default path uses spaces normally. Thank you very much, other my repos work well now.

Comment: Little note: scheme path must end with slash. "hg id --debug my://projectN" showed that scheme path is simply concatenated to repository name. So thank you, Simon, again.